# Avoiding repeated data in laravel querybuilder result

Tags: laravel

I am trying to write code to return the number of diseases diagnosed in a clinic after a given period either weekly, monthly or daily using jimmyjs laravel-report-generator using the code bellow,

```
      $fromDate =  $request->fromDate;
        $toDate  = $request->toDate;
        $sortBy = 'updated_at';
    
        $title = 'CHATTHE GROUP'; // Report title
        $subTitle = 'Mobidity Report';
        $total = 0;
    
        $meta = [ // For displaying filters description on header
            ''=> $subTitle,
            'From' => $fromDate . ' To: ' . $toDate,
            'Generated By' => Auth::user()->name
        ];
    
        $queryBuilder = Diagnosis::select(['diagnosis', 'updated_at']) // Do some querying..
                            ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$fromDate, $toDate])
                            ->distinct('diagnosis')
                            ->orderBy($sortBy, 'ASC');
    
        $columns = [ // Set Column to be displayed
            'DISEASE' => 'diagnosis',
            'NO OF CASES' => function($result){
                return Diagnosis::where('diagnosis',$result->diagnosis)->count();
            }, // if no column_name specified, this will automatically seach for snake_case of column name (will be registered_at) column from query result
            '% TOTAL' => function($result){
                return (Diagnosis::where('diagnosis',$result->diagnosis)->count()/$result->count()*100);
            }
        ];
      return ExcelReport::of($title, $meta, $queryBuilder, $columns)
                        ->editColumns(['DISEASE', '% TOTAL'], [ // Mass edit column
                            'class' => 'right bold'
                        ])
                        ->showHeader(true)
                        ->simple()
                        ->download('mobidityReport');
```

This produces the following excel file
[image: Output]
Which has the diseases repeated just as they repeat in the table, is there anyway to avoid this? I tried using distinct() but that gave an error.

Comment: what about groupBy instead of distinct?

Comment: using groupBy() gives this error ```Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'chattheclinicsystem.diagnoses.updated_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `diagnosis`, `updated_at` from `diagnoses` where `updated_at` between 2021/09/01 and 2021/11/30 group by `diagnosis` order by `updated_at` asc)```